# Not able get all user of an account of organisations in docusignapi

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am DocuSign admin api JWT access grant. I have generated the access token but I don't see sdk method in DocuSign esign client for calling admin api methods.

Please suggest how can I call DocuSign admin api using sdk. Or where to download the sdk that support admin api call. Is there any sample I can refer for calling admin api.

I want to get all accounts of  organisations.

Answer (score 0):

Anvit, at the time of this writing, we don't have an SDK for the Admin API.
You would have to make the REST API directly by using a library. For example if you're using C# - you can use RESTSharp.dll

We have a few code examples, not exactly for what you're looking for. But they provide generaal information about how to use this API. Here is the one for adding a user:
https://developers.docusign.com/orgadmin-api/code-examples/add-user

Note that this shows you how to use scripts to make the API calls, you will have to translate it for your own language.

Comment: Thanks Inbar, can I use "temporary access token" for calling admin api , just to see if I can make call to api for new user add/update to accounts in organisation account ?? Is it possible to use "temporary access token".

Comment: as long as you used the correct set of scopes when you requested it - you should be fine.

Comment: I tried the suggest way now : and found below error                                                         :Invoke-WebRequest : {"error":"unauthorized","error_description":"Not Authorized","reference_id":"9c13406a-3c8d-4c1f-bd82-e9806f0db29f"}

Comment: I can see that I am admin user in organization that I created in DocuSign - i used below scopes to generate that temporary access token response_type=code&scope=signature%20click.manage%20organization_read%20room_forms%20group_read%20permission_read%20user_read%20user_write%20account_read%20domain_read%20identity_provider_read%20dtr.rooms.read%20dtr.rooms.write%20dtr.documents.read%20dtr.documents.write%20dtr.profile.read%20dtr.profile.write%20dtr.company.read%20dtr.company.write&

Comment: I have used the same code you provided link - NOTE I have changed the Organisation id,Account id, Permission Profile Id and group id and necessary details.                   Any Suggestion !

Comment: you will have to contact support to figure out this issue unfortunately, I have seen you asked another question and I run some internal logs but it's getting complex to answer over stackoverflow.

Comment: How can reach it to them, can you please please put some light on it.

Comment: send me an email and I'll help you from there - inbar.gazit@docusign.com

Comment: I just sent you a email